# Why nothing appears in my storage space whenever dwellers collect something?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When i send to explore any Dwellers i can see the log working perfectly and also ai can see any item they collect, but when i recall them to the vault and hit the "collect" button those items just dissapear, they wont show up in my storage space, eqquiped or anything else, those items just dissapear and i´ve lose many outfits and weapons because i just noticed that; Someone have the same problem or know whats going on?

Comment: Do you have Any items in your storage space? Is the list just empty when you open it up? They wont actually appear visibly in the rooms if that is what you are going for...

Comment: Thanks for the reply James, but they just wont appear anywhere, like i said, the dwellers come with weapons and outfits, but when i tap "Collect" the items just dissapear, they dont appear inside the storage space.

Comment: Can you post us a screen shot of your storage like found here: http://i.imgur.com/YF91LbT.png Maybe if we can see what is going on we can figure it out.

Comment: Right now a dweller reach the vault and now it actually work, like i said, i tap collect and nothing happened but suddenly now an outfit and a rusty rifle just pop up in my storage... I dont know why it stop working just this day...

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/232212/14953